# Building my credit in the USA

Tags: usa, financial, credit-history, credit-cards

Referring to Philippe Leybaert's answer some time back, he stated not to give out your social security number to companies that request it.

I am applying for a secured credit card and many card companies do require your SSN. What should I do at this stage? Furthermore, before coming across this blog, I did a credit check, and I had to enter my SSN. My credit search was declined, due to not having any credit status in the US. Would this affect my credit rating now? I am a little hesitant to apply for a secured credit card just in case I am refused. Looking forward to anyone's advice.

Comment: Do you have any history in your home country with any financial institutions which also operate in the USA? I would try approaching them.

Comment: Per user16259's comment, American Express will do international transfers for clients who move to another country.

Answer (score 1):

You start at the beginning when building a credit rating in the US.
The best way to begin is with a secured credit card from a credit union and yes, you will need to present a Social Security card to get it. (ITIN is not good enough.)
A typical secured credit card is on the order of $500. Use it for a good while, build up a good credit history and when your credit scores are over, say, 700, go for an unsecured credit card.
Good luck!

Comment: Secured cards are up to whatever amount is in the security account, up to some limit the bank sets.  I've seen $2000.

Comment: If you have $2000 to spend on a secured card, that’s great, but immigrants tend to have budgets to think of..

Comment: Most actual immigration (as opposed to H1-B or J-1 visas) is family-based.  If they can afford the process they probably have some cash on hand.

Comment: I think this is subjective. Families do immigrate on H1-B / H4 visas but are not 'family based' immigration visas? Also, you can afford the process sometimes at the expense of things like large secured credit cards..